# How to remove save and reset button from edit form?

Tags: magento-1.9, adminform

In custom module I have one grid. in that grid i don't want to edit data from admin panel. I want to just view of that data so i want to remove save button and reset button.

In Edit.php

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->_objectId = "example_id";
    $this->_blockGroup = "example";
    $this->_controller = "adminhtml_example";
    // $this->_updateButton("save", "label", Mage::helper("example")->__("Save Tutor"));
    $this->_updateButton("delete", "label", Mage::helper("example")->__("Delete Tutor"));

    /**
    $this->_addButton("saveandcontinue", array(
        "label"     => Mage::helper("example")->__("Save And Continue Edit"),
        "onclick"   => "saveAndContinueEdit()",
        "class"     => "save",
    ), -100);

    $this->_formScripts[] = "
        function saveAndContinueEdit() {
            editForm.submit($('edit_form').action+'back/edit/');
        }
    ";
    */
}
```

I m comment code of save button and saveAndContinueEdit button but save button is display.

I know another way to admin can't save data using disable set as true in all addfield but i want to remove add button and reset button if possible and i want to remove this button using custom module.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add this in the method you mentioned

```
$this->_removeButton('save');
$this->_removeButton('delete');
$this->_removeButton('reset');
```

Answer (score 5):

Note that [Magento does not want you to override the `__construct` method](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php#L201-L212). You should override the `_construct` method instead. One problem is that you cannot remove buttons in the `_construct` method. But you can simply override the `_prepareLayout` method for that purpose:

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    $this->_removeButton('save');
    $this->_removeButton('delete');
    $this->_removeButton('reset');

    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}
```

Comment: That's true, but there are a lot of core classes that override the `__construct` method.

Comment: @Marius Core classes are often not good as a reference for good code style I think :D

Answer (score 4):

To remove buttons on MAGENTO 2 admin form:

```
$this->buttonList->remove('delete');
$this->buttonList->remove('save');
$this->buttonList->remove('reset');
$this->buttonList->remove('back');
```